# How to create a report with sections and page breaks using SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, bids, ssrs-grouping

I'm trying to create a report that looks like this:
[image: Tables]

using a select from this table: (fiddler [here for query and data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e359a/1))

```
CREATE TABLE StudentData
(
id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
name varchar(30),
subject varchar(30),
currentGrade varchar(2),
targetGrade varchar(2),
note1 varchar(100),
note2 varchar(100),
note3 varchar(100),
UNIQUE (id)
)
```

Basically I want to display each `student` on a new page, with their `subject` split up into sections, and their `grades` and `notes` in each of these `subject` sections.

I am trying to do this within *Business Intelligence Development Studio*

Any help with how I would go about that would be great, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you go through the New Report wizard? It will walk you through most of this. If you don't want to use the wizard, then look at some of the MSDN tutorials.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I can upload the images now.

1. First you add a **List** Tablix to the report with the name and add a **TextBox**
   [image]
2. Add a **Parent Group** to the list in the **Row Group** category
   [image]
3. Choose **name** as the **Group By** Column
   [image]
4. You will have two columns, one with the group and another with the TextBox created previously
   [image]
5. Add more **TextBox** with the rest of the columns missing.
   [image]
6. Now we're going to set the break on each group, select on the **Row Groups** section the group name and right click and select **Group Properties**
   [image]
7. Select the **Page Break** page and then check the option **Between each instance of a group**
   [image]
8. You should have something like this now.
   [image]
9. Now let's configure the name to appear to the top of each page, select in the **Row Groups** section the **Details** Group and add a **Total Before**
   [image]
10. And after add some TextBox and some colors you will have something like this.
    [image]

I hope this can help you.

Comment: This was a great help to solve a problem I was having with a report.  I see this only places the name at the top of the group.  How would I display the name at the top of every page for that group?

Answer (score 1):

Add a List and set the DataSetName to your existing Dataset. In the Row Groups definition for the list, tell it to Group on id. Add a textbox for the name.

Add another List inside the existing List and set the DataSetName to your existing Dataset. In the Row Groups definition for the list, tell it to Group on subject. Add a textbox for the subject.

Add 2 Tables inside the inner List to present your inner-most tables.