# displaying all groups of data in ssrs

Tags: sql, reporting-services

i have a student table that has each student with 10 rows for the 10 subjects he undertakes
.in the header section there is a field for school name and students name in the body section there is a table with subject and scores when i use a filter of one student it displays expected results but when i do not apply filters it displays only one name in the headers section and a continuous rows of all student record but i want it to display each student name and school name on different pages plus their records[This are part of the desired results[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6iBp.png)

[This is how each page should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF6OW.png)

Comment: provide sample data with image so we can better understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly you want to show student detail on each page (one student on one page if 10 student show 10 page) right ?

First, Add List to you body and move all control to List then group on student name or unique field to student.

Then. In List Properties Set Page break between each instance of a group.

you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257276/how-to-create-a-report-with-sections-and-page-breaks-using-ssrs) to guide.