# Add line break for each category in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I'd like to add an extra line after every category in SSRS..Not sure how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13258700/2647648)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a report with sections and page breaks using SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257276/how-to-create-a-report-with-sections-and-page-breaks-using-ssrs)

Answer (score 1):

Create a second blank detail row above the detail row with your fields on it. Select this second blank detail row and in the `Visibility`-`Hidden` property, put the expression:

```
=Fields!category.Value = Previous(Fields!category.Value)
```

In other words, when the category field on this row is the same as the previous category, hide the blank line. So when they aren't the same, the blank line appears.